# SQLAlchemy why have model classes inherit from class Base(DeclarativeBase) instead of DeclarativeBase directly?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

The ORM quickstart guide for SQLAlchemy 2.0 defines a practice where you should define a simple child class of `DeclarativeBase` and let all your model classes inherit from that.

Example straight from the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/quickstart.html#learn-the-above-concepts-in-depth):

```
>>> class Base(DeclarativeBase):
...     pass

>>> class User(Base):
...     __tablename__ = "user_account"
...     # more stuff here

>>> class Address(Base):
...     __tablename__ = "address"
...     # more stuff here
```

Now I'm wondering why this is defined the "standard" approach instead of just letting all my model classes inherit from `DeclarativeBase` directly, as `Base` doesn't seem to add any additional functionality? Something like

```
>>> class User(DeclarativeBase):
...     __tablename__ = "user_account"
...     # more stuff here

>>> class Address(DeclarativeBase):
...     __tablename__ = "address"
...     # more stuff here
```

Comment: See the comments for the DeclarativeBase class starting [here](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/66cb236856cb458f34b5aa1e4f2ec737e1e45f76/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/decl_api.py#L643)